# On-premises SQL backup to Azure recovery service

Tags: sql-server, azure, system-center

We would like to backup our on-premises SQL server to Azure Recovery Service Vault. We tried to use the Azure Backup Server but there is a domain dependency.

Is there a way to use Azure Backup Server or System Center 2016 without having your servers in a specific domain ? The SQL server has the default WORKGROUP domain.

What would be the best alternative solution to backup a SQL on-premises server to Azure Recovery Service without adding the server to a domain ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-microsoft-azure-backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to use the build-in SQL BACKUP command to URL. This URL is in our case the Azure Storage account.

See documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919148%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

The backup file is a blob type. But there is a restriction you can not use a "Blob purpose" Azure storage account because this gives you a 400 Bad Request. It is possible to backup your SQL database in a "General Purpose" Azure storage account.